# Is my proof by mathematical induction that $n(n+2)$ is divisble by 4 correct?

Tags: solution-verification, induction

**Problem:**

Prove that $n(n+2)$ is divisible by $4$ by using mathematical induction, if $n$ is any even positive integer.

**My attempt:**

$P(q):$ "$2q(2q+2)$ is divisible by $4$", where $q$ is a natural number. Note that we get the original expression if we substitute $2q$ with $n$.

**Basis step:**

$P(1)$ is true because $2(1)(2(1)+2)=8$ is divisible by $4$.

**Inductive step:**

*Inductive hypothesis:* Let $P(k)$ is true, where $k$ is any arbitrary natural number.

Now, we must show that $P(k+1)$ is also true under this assumption. That is, we have to show that

$$(2k+2)(2k+2+2)=(2k+2)(2k+4)=4(k+1)(k+2)$$ is divisible by $4$.

$4(k+1)(k+2)$ is divisible by $4$.

Both the basis and inductive steps have been proved. So, $P(q)$ is always true, where $q$ is a natural number. In other words, $n(n+2)$ is divisible by $4$.

**My question:**

Is my proof correct? We did not need to use the inductive hypothesis at all, which we usually do. Is that okay?

Comment: @HappyDay That was intentional, and was what was asked of them.  Of course $n(n+2)$ is not divisible by $4$ for odd $n$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I misread the question.

Comment: @ OP, this is a correct proof, though as you pointed out this is not really a proof *by induction* but is rather a direct proof.  I suppose if you insist on phrasing this by induction, you could try to fiddle with it all, writing as $(2k+2)(2k+2+2) = (2k)(2k+2)+4k+8+4k+4$... and using the induction hypothesis for the piece on the left and elementary number theory to say the items on the right are all multiples of four...  Personally, I see this as a problem with the question itself and would not have asked this question in such a way as to imply it needed induction.

Comment: I assume the intention of the problem was starting with $n=2$, and then showing the statement is true for $n=k+2$ if it is true for $n=k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof looks ok, though, as you said, induction is not needed for it. One can simply notice that if $n$ is even, then $n=2k$ which means $$n(n+2) = 2k (2k + 2) = 2\cdot k \cdot 2 \cdot (k+1) = 4\cdot k(k+1)$$ and the final expression is obviously divisible by $4$.

Comment: Maybe the person who originally posed the question wanted us to notice that $(n+2)(n+4) = n(n+2) + 4(n+2)$, assert that $n(n+2)$ is a multiple of 4 by induction, etc, etc.

Comment: @kimchilover My course instructor told us to prove by induction, so I will go with your suggestion, and discard my attempt.

Comment: It’s even a multiple of 8

Answer (score 1):

Define $P(n): n(n+2) \space \text{is divisible by} \space 4$.

Clearly $P(0)$ is true ($0$ is divisible by $4$). Now, let's assume $P(k)$ is true. We are left with showing that $P(k+2)$ is true. In other words, we know $k(k+2)$ is divisible by $4$, and would like to show that $(k+2)(k+2+2)$ is also divisible by $4$.

$$(k+2)(k+2+2)=(k+2)(k+4)=k(k+2)+4(k+2)$$

Obviously $4(k+2)$ is divisible by $4$, and by our induction hypothesis so is $k(k+2)$. Thus, we have a sum of two terms that are divisible by $4$, which is also divisible by $4$. This is precisely what we needed to prove.

By the way, your proof is technically correct, though as you mentioned, it is not really induction,

Comment: I'm nitpicking: basis case is slightly wrong. P(0) is not valid as the basis step since 0 is not positive.

Comment: Ok, I extended the proof to all non-negative integers ;)